# Java: How to replace all occurances of a character if and only if followed by some other character

Tags: java, regex

In particular: I want to replace all occurances of a full stop \. with a full stop plus white space \.\s if the full stop is immediately followed by an upper case character [A-Z].

Any suggestions? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
yourstring.replaceAll("\\.([A-Z])",". $1")
```

Comment: thanks - that's it - couldn't figure out how to do the back ref.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the regex `s/\.([A-Z])/. \1/g`, like so:

```
myString.replaceAll("\\.([A-Z])", ". $1");
```

For more, see the [`Pattern`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class and [`String.replaceAll`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)). Note that backslashes need to be escaped themselves, hence the double backslashes.

Comment: Hi Stephan - thanks for help - however not quite there: the second arg to replaceAll is a string literal, not a regex, so the back ref \\1 is not interpreted

Comment: @Richard: You're right. I just noticed this after testing it. Fixed it. (Initially I wrote the code by just looking at the documentation, which I apparently misinterpreted.)

Answer (score 0):

why not use positive lookahed?

(\\\.)(?=[A-Z])